# Como listar os telefones de todos os contatos?

Tags: android

Estou querendo saber: Como listar todos os contatos(numero do telefone e nome do contado) do celular?

Comment: Acho que este artigo pode te ajudar http://www.frameworksystem.com/blog/mobile-lendo-lista-de-contatos-do-android/

Comment: @DaniloOliveira obrigado, se você quiser postar como resposta para ganhar pontuação fique a vontade.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Espero que este artigo tenha lhe ajudado @PedroRangel, boa sote com o desenvolvimento :)
http://www.frameworksystem.com/blog/mobile-lendo-lista-de-contatos-do-android/